# Where and how can I host small ASP .NETCore + React JS application with small MS SQL DB

Tags: asp.net, .net, reactjs

Where and how can I host small ASP .NETCore  + React JS application with small MS SQL DB.

Comment: You can check out asphostportal if you want to host .NET Core with MSSQL server.

Answer (score 0):

The app can be hosted at Heroku.

There's a great free tier during development x POC phases.

“Deploy asp.net core 2.0 apps on Heroku” por Ikechi Michael https://link.medium.com/2hCmzAI1YZ

But AFAIK there's no MS SQL free hosting. So I recommend you starting with an open source database like MySQL.

As long as you're using an ORM like Entity Framework, it's possible to change with little effort after the app goes big.